# Editing source in multiple instances of sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm used to edit my sources in 2 instances and every time I save changes in one instance the others in which the same source is opened offer me to reload source from the disk and delete all changes I've made in that instances. I wonder is there a way to make sublime 'add' changes from disk if the source changed (like scm git do).
Thank you!

Comment: just wondering: why are you editing in two places at once? If you're doing that, you should probably be using version control and merging your changes when done. There are Git plugins for Sublime, I can expand this to a full answer if you want...

Comment: @MattDMo of course technically I can't edit source in two places simultaneously ), but I can view one source in two different places. Though not often it appears it is quite convinient not to browse to already viewed on other monitor function, but just to switch to other monitor and continue edit there )))

Comment: I think in this case there's a good reason to adjust your workflow so that you're only actively editing in one place at a time. Otherwise, there's just too much danger of losing your work. Using Git, you could theoretically make 2 commits of the same file, then do a merge later on, but it makes much more sense to me to just have one window/monitor devoted to editing, and any others (if needed) **just** for viewing - no changes allowed. For example, I keep Sublime open for editing, and if I need to just view something quickly I'll use `cat` on the command line.